# UWP ListView DataTemplate Bind to Item instead of Property

Tags: xaml, listview, data-binding, uwp

How do you bind an item in a data template to the item itself, instead of a property of that item?

I have a user control that takes an item as a model. Given these models:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public Car Model { get; set; }
}

public MyPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Car> CareList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do something like this in XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind CarList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Car">
            <StackPanel>

                <!-- Binding to properties of Car is simple... -->
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}">

                <!-- But what if I want to bind to the car itself ??? -->
                <userControls:MyUserControl Model="{x:Bind Car}">
                </userControls:MyUserControl>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Not sure about uwp, but perhaps you could do just `{x:Bind}`? (analogous to using `"{Binding}"` in WPF when binding against the DataContext / item itself)

Comment: That appears to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from @user2819245 is correct, if you do not specify the `Path` of the binding then the `DataContext` object will be bound directly instead.

> In UWP, if your list source can change at runtime or is delay loaded, then you may also need to specify the `Mode=OneWay`, this is due to `{x:Bind}` defaulting to a *OneTime* binding mode.
>
> > This example includes how to set the `Mode` property in both use cases

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind CarList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Car">
            <StackPanel>

                <!-- Binding to properties of Car is simple... -->
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}">

                <!-- Binding to the car itself (as the DataContext of this template) -->
                <userControls:MyUserControl Model="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}">
                </userControls:MyUserControl>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```