# How to bind to a model in ListView instead of property in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3, xbind

I am trying to directly bind to a model ([similar to the situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657957/xbind-in-uwp-universal-windows-platform)), instead of the property on that model, but it is not working. [I previously asked a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093977/uwp-listview-datatemplate-bind-to-item-instead-of-property), and the answer had worked in UWP. I am now working in WinUI3 (packaged UWP) and am not sure if the same solution applies.

I have a class:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I have a UserControl that displays that class:

```
public sealed partial class MessageControl : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The message to display.
    /// </summary>
    public Message Message { get; set; }

    public MessageControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

With XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MessageClient.Controls.EmailControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MessageClient.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Displays the title of the message. -->
            <TextBlock Name="HeaderTextBlock"
                       Text="{x:Bind Message.Title, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
        
            <!-- Displays the content of the message. -->
            <TextBlock Name="ContentPreviewTextBlock"
                       Text="{x:Bind Message.Content, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, I have a Window I am displaying that control on, inside of a list view:

```
<Window
    x:Class="MessageClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:EmailClient"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:controls="using:MessageClient.Controls" xmlns:models="using:MessageClient.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <!-- The list of messages. -->
        <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Messages}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Message">
                    <controls:MessageControl Margin="5"
                                           Message="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}"></controls:MessageControl>

                    <!-- TEST 1 -->
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"></TextBlock>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <!-- TEST 2 -->
        <!--<controls:MessageControl Message="{x:Bind TestMessage, Mode=OneWay}"></controls:MessageControl>-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind for the Window is:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages;
    public Message TestMessage;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Populate the test message.
        this.PopulateTestMessages();
    }

    private void PopulateTestMessages()
    {
        // The TestDataGenerator just returns a staticaly defined list of test messages.
        this.Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>(TestDataGenerator.GetTestMessages(10));
        this.TestMessage = this.Messages.First();
    }
}
```

When I run this code (which compiles and runs), I get a window with the expected number of items in the `ListView` (10), but they are all blank. There are also no XAML binding failures being reported (via the new feature in Visual Studio 2022). In an attempt to investigate this, I added in a textblock inside of the listview (denoted as TEST 1 in the comments) bound to the `Title` property of the `Message`. This worked as expected, displaying the correct titles for the 10 messages. I then added a single `MessageControl` to the `Window` outside of the `ListView` (denoted as TEST 2 in the comments) bound to a single `Message` property on the `Window`. This also worked exactly as expected.

Am I missing something? Why does the specific case of binding to a model directly (as opposed to a property on that model - i.e. a binding with no path) not work, when the data is there and works with other binding configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this specific case exposes some of the ordering of how bindings work in XAML. To understand what is happening here:

1. The `Window` is being initialized, which initializes its UI, including the `ListView`.
2. The `Message` models are then retrieved and added to the `ObservableCollection`.
3. When each `Message` is added to the `ObservableCollection`, the `ListView` using that `ObservableCollection` as its `ItemsSource` then creates a new `Item` using the `ItemTemplate` specified in the XAML, and then initializes and binds the newly initialized `MessageControl` to the `Message`. The TEST 1 verifies this is happening.

The problem here is in step 3: The `MessageControl`s are initialized AND THEN bound to. When the binding happens, the UI is never notified that it needs to update the binding. This is why adding `Mode=OneWay` to the `{x:Bind}` doesn't fix the issue. The `OneWay` mode tells the binding to update whenever the model updates... but the XAML is still never aware the model was updated.

I am not entirely sure why this is different than the other two bindings (the TEST 1 and TEST 2 comments), but this seems to be an issue with user-defined types (classes) specifically, and NOT with primitive or built-in type properties (such as `string` and `int`).

The fix is to enable the model to inform (or "notify") the UI that is has been updated. This is done be implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Update the `MessageControl` to:

```
public sealed partial class MessageControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Message _message;
    /// <summary>
    /// The message to display.
    /// </summary>
    public Message Message
    {
        get { return this._message; }
        set
        {
            this._message = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public EmailControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

A final note: implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` MUST be done on the `MessageControl` for this to work. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Message` model would allow for the `MessageControl` (or any other data bound UI, such as the commented TEST 1) to update if a particular property of the `Message` model updates, but does not fix the issue of the `Message` model iself on the `MessageControl` being updated.

Comment: I will! Github will not allow me to accept my own answer until 48 hours have passed.