# How to bind a datatype to a control in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, winui-3

I have a datatype (model) I would like to display the data for in my UI by showing several properties using data binding.. It works in a `GridView` or `ListView`, but how do I do this when I only want a single model bound instead of a collection?

To do this with a collection, the following works in a `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Shapes, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Shape">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind NumberOfSides}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Color}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

On a page with a `ObservableCollection` of type `Shape` called `Shapes`:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    // ...
    public ObservableCollection<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

With the following model `Shape`:

```
public class Shape
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfSides { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I **want** to do something like this, but this does not work:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind NumberOfSides}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Color}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The data-binding is actually being done to the `ListView`, and the `DataTemplate` is simply declaring the layout to display the bound model with.

To accomplish this with a single bound item instead of a collection, you need to use a control that still has a template property. This is where the `ContentControl` comes in ([Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol?view=winrt-22621)). The `ContentControl` has a `ContentTemplate` property, which can contain a `DataTemplate` the same way a `ListView` or `GridView` can! You can then set the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` in the C# code, or bind to it (the same way you would bind to an `ItemsSource` property of a `ListView` or `GridView`, only with a single item instead of a collection).

### The Simple Way

The following example works (Note that the `DataTemplate` and all of it's children are identical to how they would appear in a `ListView` or `GridView`):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Shape">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind NumberOfSides}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Color}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Then in your C# code:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    // ...
    public void SetShape(Shape shape)
    {
        this.MyContentControl.Content = shape;
    }
    // ...
}
```

### The FULL Data Binding Way

You can also use data binding to bind to the shape property, but this will require some more work. Start by adding the binding to the `ContentControl` as follows:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl"
                Content="{x:Bind MyShape}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
         <!-- Contents all the same as before -->
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

And add the `MyShape` property to bind to on `MyPage`:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    // ...
    public Shape MyShape { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

As is, this will not work. It may work when you set it initially, but if you change `MyShape`, the bound UI will not update.

Notice that if you were using `ObservableCollection` (such as in the `ListView` example), you can get the UI to update when you call `Add()` or `Remove()` functions of the `ObservableCollection`, but *not when you change the `ObservableCollection` reference itself*. The reason is that the `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is what tells the bindings to update when you change the set of items in the collection. The following will **not** automatically work:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    // ...
    public Shape MyShape { get; set; }
    // ...
    public void UpdateShape(Shape newShape)
    {
        this.MyShape = newShape;
    }
}
```

To get this to work, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MyPage`. This requires three steps (which may sound intimidating, but work the same way for any property):

1. Implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. Add the `PropertyChanged` event.
3. Modify the `MyShape` setter to raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
}
```

Add the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
/// <summary>
/// Raise the PropertChanged event for the given property name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Name of the property changed.</param>
public void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
{
    // Ensure a handler is listening for the event.
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Modify the `MyShape` setter to raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
private Shape myShape;
public Shape MyShape
{
    get => this.myShape;
    set
    {
        this.myShape = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyShape");
    }
}
```

Your final C# code will look like this:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...

    private Shape myShape;
    public Shape MyShape
    {
        get => this.myShape;
        set
        {
            this.myShape = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyShape");
        }
    }

    // ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Raise the PropertChanged event for the given property name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name of the property changed.</param>
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        // Ensure a handler is listening for the event.
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    // ...

    public void UpdateShape(Shape newShape)
    {
        this.MyShape = newShape;
    }
}
```

NOW your `ContentControl` will work as expected with the different `BindingMode` values (`OneTime`, `OneWay`, and `TwoWay`).

If you want your bound controls WITHIN the `ContentControl` to update when you change a property of the shape, such as have the `<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}">` update when you do:

```
this.MyShape.Name = "A New Name";
```

You can similarly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Shape` class itself with the same basic steps. This is the same whether you are using a `ContentControl`, `GridView`, `ListView`, or any other data-bound control. Basically, **each** layer you want to be able to update the properties of, and have a data bound UI update, you need to do this. This also needs to be done regardless of which of the two ways you used from this answer. You can refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063213/how-to-bind-to-a-model-in-listview-instead-of-property-in-winui3) for details on this.

Comment: You can use the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** NuGet package and remove a bunch of boilerplate code.